# Translation from binary into decimal numbers in C++

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, calculation

I tried to build a function that calculates a binary number stored in a string into a decimal number stored in a `long long`. I'm thinking that my code should work but it doesn't.

In this example for the binary number `101110111` the decimal number is `375`. But my output is completely confusing.

Here is my code:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    std::string stringNumber = "101110111";

    const char *array = stringNumber.c_str();
    int subtrahend = 1;
    int potency = 0;
    long long result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(array); i++) {
        result += pow(array[strlen(array) - subtrahend] * 2, potency);
        subtrahend++;
        potency++;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1
99
9703
894439
93131255
9132339223
894974720087
76039722530902
8583669948348758
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Maybe unrelated: You can use a `std::string` exactly like a `const char*` since it overloads the subscript operator `[]`. It's even better, because it has a `length()`-function that you can use instead of `strlen`. You could remove `array` completely.

Comment: And a little hint: `'1' != 1` but `'1' == 49`

Comment: See [ASCII Table & Description](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'1' != 1` as mentioned in the comments by @churill. `'1' == 49`. If you are on linux type `man ascii` in terminal to get the ascii table.

Try this, it is the same code. I just used the `stringNumber` directly instead of using `const char*` to it. And I subtracted `'0'` from the current index. `'0' == 48`, so if you subtract it, you get the actual `1` or `0` integer value:

```
    auto sz = stringNumber.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        result += pow((stringNumber[sz - subtrahend] - '0') * 2, potency);
        subtrahend++;
        potency++;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
```

Moreover, use the methods provided by `std::string` like `.size()` instead of doing `strlen()` on every iteration. Much faster.

---

In a production environment, I would highly recommend using [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) instead of rolling your own solution:

```
    std::string stringNumber = "1111";
    std::bitset<64> bits(stringNumber);
    bits.to_ulong();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting to convert your digits into integers. Plus you really don't need to use C strings.

Here's a better version of the code

```
int main() {
    std::string stringNumber = "101110111";

    int subtrahend = 1;
    int potency = 0;
    long long result = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < stringNumber.size(); i++) {
        result += pow(2*(stringNumber[stringNumber.size() - subtrahend] - '0'), potency);
        subtrahend++;
        potency++;
        std::cout << result << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Subtracting `'0'` from the string digits converts the digit into an integer.

Now for extra credit write a version that doesn't use `pow` (hint: `potency *= 2;` instead of `potency++;`)

Answer (score 1):

c++ way

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::string stringNumber = "101110111";   
    long long result = 0;

    uint string_length = stringNumber.length();

    for(int i = 0; i <string_length; i++) {
      if(stringNumber[i]=='1')
      {
        long pose_value = pow(2, string_length-1-i);        
        result += pose_value;
      }       
        
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```