# Potency-function in c++ drops confusing results

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, pow

I tried to script a function which are able to convert binary numbers into decimal numbers. But unfortunately the results of the potency-calculations which need to be added at the end are very confusing. What I'm doing wrong here?

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    std::string label = "10110";
    int subtrahend = 1;
    int potency = 0;
    int result = 0;
    int positionResult;

    for(int i = 0; i < label.length(); i++) {

        positionResult= pow(label[label.length() - subtrahend] * 2, potency);
        std::cout << positionResult<< std::endl;

        result += positionResult;
        subtrahend++;
        potency++;
    }
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
98
9604
884736
92236816
93131255
```

Comment: You don't need to introduce floating point functions such as `pow` to convert binary to decimal.

Comment: Seems to be a good time to learn what a debugger is

Comment: [Very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769590/translation-from-binary-into-decimal-numbers-in-c/62769771#62769771), with nearly identical code got asked recently. Must be homework I guess. Answer is the same as it was back then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with bitwise operator

or

Your answer is -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
std::string label = "10110";
int subtrahend = 1;
int result = 0;
int positionResult;

for(int i = 0; i < label.length(); i++) {

    positionResult= pow(2,label.length() - subtrahend)*(label[i]-'0');
    std::cout << positionResult<< std::endl;

    result += positionResult;
    subtrahend++;
}
std::cout << result << std::endl;
}
```